# Is it possible to get exception report csv file in locust.io when its running without web

Tags: python, csv, performance-testing, locust

Now i am able to get stats , failures , stats history csv files in without web.
by using this command :
locust -f locustfile.py  --headless -u 10 -r 1 --csv=../../csv/$USER --run-time 1m

Is it possible to get exceptions csv file in without web ???
this feature is available in web but not in without web.

Comment: if its available how to get it.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a PR to solve this issue that you have reported

https://github.com/locustio/locust/pull/1674